# How to create .XAP extension file for windows phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have created a new Windows 8 JavaScript project using phoneGap,

My question is 
how can i get .XAP extension file in Bin folder
as this is mandatory to run my application on windows device.

And also tell me one thing there is any other solution to make this .XAP extension file.
Because of using javascript i am not getting .XAP extension file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to check that you are configured for [windows 8](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%208) or [windows phone 8](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone).

If you compile it as Windows Phone Project then you can get XAP from your project.  Bin>>Debug>>Your project.XAP

Comment: Thanks Imran for your appropriate response,

configured for Window phone 8,  

While compiling my window phone project i am getting these file in  Bin>>Debug as given below,

AppX Folder,

AppxManifest.xml
,
ProjectName.build
,
resources.pri

Comment: Welcome Gaurav. if you are satisfied with answer then click as accepted answer

Comment: Hi Imran, actually i am not having solution of my issue, so i am just still looking for solution.

Comment: Have you configured visual studio [Phone gap windows phone 8  Templates](http://phonegap.com/download#autodownload) properly ?

Comment: I have configured VS 2012 with phoneGap Using Javascript Project and added PhoneGap references manually. With the help of this url (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/527393/Using-PhoneGap-in-Windows-Store-Applications)

Comment: OK got it as already  I told you your configured solution is for W8 or WP 8 , this article written for Windows 8 not for windows phone 8 . Keep in mind windows 8  and windows phone 8 both is different. Create new project as per http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

You must either compile it, as a Windows Phone project, using Visual Studio. Or alternatively use the Adobe PhoneGap Build service, which allows you to send your code to the 'cloud' as a zip file. It will them build your app, returning IPA, APK, XAP and other native bundles.